# VB.Net concatenating strings, adding strange spaces

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I'm sending a function a structure property that's a string (that's been already processed). It's an IP addr. Specifically:

```
 Dim ipaddr As String = "192.168.2.112"
```

At least, this is the value that we get after I do some processing. It looks like this in my local variable window mid build, so I know that it's looking ok. I'm trying to make a request string for the HTTP command. So I concatenate like so:

```
 Dim ReqStr As String = "http://" & ipaddr & "/cgi-bin/cmd/"
```

BUT doing so makes these strange spaces! As in the resulting string is

```
"http://192.168.2.112   /cgi-bin/cmd"
```

I thought the resulting code was maybe getting non ASCII character values, so I put it though a "\S+" regular expression, or I did ipaddr.trimend() or .trim, etc. ALL of these add the spaces. When I look at ipaddr in the locals when building, it ends at the proper end of the ipaddr value.

Yet, when I just put a hard coded string ("192.168.2.112") into the ipaddr's place in the string concatenation, no spaces. How do I get rid of the "secret" ascii characters I can't see?

### Edit

Here is a sample of code which reproduces the problem:

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = {49, 57, 50, 46, 49, 54, 56, 46, 50, 46, 49, 49, 50, 0, 0, 0}
Dim ipaddr As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
Dim ReqStr As String = "http://" & ipaddr.TrimEnd() & "/cgi-bin/cmd/"
```

Comment: why using "&" to concate strings??

Comment: @neel because that is how you do it in VB.NET

Comment: @Neel, because that is the standard string concatenation operator in VB.NET.

Comment: ok but why there is nothing like "&" here http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat-vbnet? @MattWilko and steven

Comment: The code above works as expected, no strange chars in the resulting string. If you get that result then something else is at work here

Comment: @Neel while it is a good site, it is hardly the reference for VB.NET

Comment: @neel - you should use MSDN as the official source. Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx

Comment: While debugging, please open your **Immediate Window** and type `?System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ReqStr)` and press enter.  Then copy and paste the output of that command into your question.  That will help us to reproduce and better understand your problem.

Comment: ok thanx @MattWilko and Steve I didn't know about "&" I always thought its possible with "+"

Comment: Ah, I see your thinking. ipaddr is processed from a ip packet that is sent over the internet. I think maybe I'm not processing it enough to get rid of it. Here's the values:

Comment: It came up as a nothing byte() i'll try it differently.

Comment: Here's the ASCII array of byte() of the reqstr. I think this is the source of the issue (I didn't put the whole value to avoid spamming):  (0) 104 Byte
  (1) 116 Byte
  (2) 116 Byte
  (3) 112 Byte
  (4) 58 Byte
  (5) 47 Byte
  (6) 47 Byte
  (7) 49 Byte
  (8) 57 Byte
  (9) 50 Byte
  (10) 46 Byte
  (11) 49 Byte
  (12) 54 Byte
  (13) 56 Byte
  (14) 46 Byte
  (15) 50 Byte
  (16) 46 Byte
  (17) 49 Byte
  (18) 49 Byte
  (19) 50 Byte
  (20) 0 Byte
  (21) 0 Byte
  (22) 0 Byte
  (23) 47 Byte
  (24) 99 Byte
  (25) 103 Byte
  (26) 105 Byte
  (27) 45 Byte
  (28) 98 Byte
  (29) 105 Byte
  (30) 110 Byte

Comment: How did you get that byte array?  That doesn't look like Unicode, as I asked for.

Comment: I had a predone function that takes a ascii string and turns it into an array. But! You were on the right path, and I see my problem. After the "2" character there are three null ascii characters that are there. It needs more processing.

Comment: There's no such thing as an ASCII string in .NET, at least not with the built-in types.  All `String` objects are stored in unicode.  The only way to represent ASCII data in .NET is as a list of bytes.  In any case, though, yes, those null characters are the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The byte array that you posted shows that you have [`NUL` characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) in your string so the standard `Trim` won't work as this only removes spaces.

Try using the [overloaded Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which accepts characters to Remove the null characters:

```
Dim ReqStr As String = "http://" & ipaddr.Trim(Convert.ToChar(0)) & "/cgi-bin/cmd/"
```

A better solution might be to use the [`IPAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Type (from the `System.Net` namespace) to hold your IP address. This won't solve your problem but it will throw a runtime error converting your rogue array into an address:

```
Dim ip As IPAddress = Nothing
If Not IPAddress.TryParse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes), ip) Then
    'ip address is not valid
End If
Dim ReqStr As String = "http://" & ip.ToString & "/cgi-bin/cmd/"
```